# Tensorflow: Issue with training size in each epoch

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am building a basic neural network using Keras and Tensorflow using mnist dataset using the following code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28*28).astype('float32') / 255.0 
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28*28).astype('float32') / 255.0 
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

model = keras.Sequential(
            [
                keras.Input(shape=(28*28)),
                layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
                layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
                layers.Dense(10), 
            ]
        )

model.compile(
                loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                metrics = ['accuracy'],
             )

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

My output is:

[image]

As we can see in the image above, each epoch is only going through 1875 (=60000/32) data points. Shouldn't it go through all the 60000 instances per epoch as there are 60000 records in training dataset?

Comment: Searching the site should be always your first option, as this has been asked many many times before.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I missed it somehow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's 1875 batches not 1875 data points. In each epoch it goes though all the data points.

Comment: Okay thanks. And do you know how can I display number of data points instead of batches?

Comment: No, i have never tried. because i dont need.

Comment: @DumbCoder You need a custom callback for this, you can not just alter the default Keras progress bar.